# Change search location in Spring boot 1.3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like externalize the configuration of my aplication, I use Spring Boot 1.3.0, and I kwnow that the class ConfigFileApplicationListener has a default value DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS. How can I change the source of my configuration, before this class load the default properties source?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PropertySource annotation on your configuration class (which is annotated @SpringBootApplication or @Configuration).

Like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:other.properties", "file:./other-external.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class MyApplication {
```

It will search first other.properties in your classpath and then looks the external file other-external.properties right outside of your jar or war file. Latest files overwrites values of other files (if they exists)

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html for more details.

Comment: This is a solution, but there is not the best solution. At the end I have built my own DefaultConfigFileApplicationListener.

Comment: Can you please explain, why is this not the best solution?